# knockout-validation should the validation message be displayed by default?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the knockout-validation plugin, I've created an async rule as per:

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Async-Rules

Should the validation trigger the display normal default validation messages?

Although I can see from `.isValidating.subscribe` that it is being validated, I'm unsure whether the validation message is meant to display as well or whether I have to customise this myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should display the message. But the messages are only displayed if the observable is invalid AND is modified `observable.isModified() === true`.

You could check that by changing the value of your observable.